# Drupal/Ubercart UK payment Gateway that does'nt require PCI DSS compliance

Tags: drupal, payment-gateway, ubercart, pci-dss

Im looking for a Drupal6/ubercart2 payment module for any UK payment gateway which does'nt require PCI DSS compliance. My website is a relatively low transaction shoppingcart and acquiring compliance is over the budget.

For example, there is a module for 'Sage pay go direct' which requires the compliance. Sagepay also offers another solution called 'Sage Pay Go with Form' in which a customer is redirected to their site to store card details and make payments but as far as I know, there are no modules available.

Worldpay has a module but requires compliance.

We have the paypal module which I'm leaving as a last option as it requires users to create an account which is a bit off putting.

Any other gateway modules or cheap PCI-DSS compliant hosting providers anyone can recommend?

Comment: I will can aslo consider a non UK-based gateway as long as it accepts payment in £s.

Answer (score 1):

If your payment is processed by a third party (ie. Paypal, Sage) then you don't need to worry about PCI compliance for the most part, as it deals with the storage of payment information.

Also, Paypal Website Payments Standard has no monthly costs and does not require a Paypal account, users can pay using a credit card without signing up.

For smaller eCommerce clients (under around $2,000 per month) then it makes sense to use Paypal's free option (3% transaction fee). For higher volumes it starts to make sense to pay for a merchant account.